# VSCode folder structure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to change the folder structure.. if you see in the folder "utils" i have another folder called "mocks" well.. what i want is change the structure to see 1 folder by folder.. something like this

[image]

Like the "services" folder which have just a 1 file.. i have the same structure, 1 folder inside another and 1 file but in the structure i see 1 folder in the same line. I don't know if i explained me

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a setting: `explorer.compactFolders`.

More info here: [Compact folders in Explorer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#compact-folders-in-explorer).

> In the File Explorer, we now render single child folders in a compact form. In such a form, single child folders will be compressed in a combined tree element. Useful for Java package structures, for example.
>
> Setting `explorer.compactFolders` controls this behavior. By default, this setting is turned **on**.

Answer (score 15):

In VS Code we have a Setting called `Compact File Structure`.

If that setting is On then we Compact the structure.

How to turn it off?

1. Go to settings
2. Search for: Compact File
3. Uncheck The compact file structure
4. Save the file

Done.