# Viusal Studio code create a file in child directory but appear in parrent folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory

i am in visual studio code with python and i have a folder with the name parrent and inside of the folder there is another one folder called child, in the child i have a code that creates a a audio.mp3 file, the file appears in the parrent folder instead of child folder

Comment: be sure to set the `cwd` option of the launch config to the correct directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

look at this.

[look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803993/vscode-folder-structure)

exists an option to change folder tree:

explorer.compactFolders(it is enabled by default)